# How to prevent hyperlinking of the grand-child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

How can i make the `.no-click` *div* clickable without going to the *http://example.com* page? Can anyone help me out?

Here is an example https://lajumate.ro/ this is web page with ads, if you hover over the ad the share button and the save button shows up and it`s clickable (the button`s are inside the href)

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.no-click {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="no-click">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: can you explain it more? you want the div to be clickable but not using a href?

Comment: You can add `.no-click:hover { cursor: pointer }` so it will change the cursor on hover, and then handle the click in javascript

Comment: Do you want any functionality when you click on that div or you just want to show the pointer cursor when you are on it?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is to use [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), which is a newer method of its historical alias [`cancelBubble`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble), and cancel's the event bubbling.

In some situations [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) can work, though do note, it doesn't cancel the bubbling but can have a similar effect.

*Updated: It appears this won't work unless it is also combined with `preventDefault`. Will have a look later, to see why is that.*

Stack snippet

```js
var no_click = document.querySelector('.no-click');
no_click.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();    //temp. update, though this should NOT be needed
  console.log('hey');
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.no-click {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="no-click">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: this is the answer i wanted to post. But in my testing environment, stopPropagation doesn't work. But it should. ( preventDefault is NOT the right solution from my point of view ) . https://jsfiddle.net/tfxco7up/ Can you tell me why this doesn't work ? does it have to to with jsfiddle handling the links ? Also in your answer, clicking on the red div, shouldn't redirect you to example.com ?

Comment: @MihaiT Actually I don't, as my snippet above does work. Doesn't my above snippet work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. But i cannot figure out why in jsfiddle it does not :) . Also in your answer, clicking on the red div, shouldn't it redirect you to example.com ?

Comment: @MihaiT It appears to be something with Fiddle not cancel the bubbling. When clicking on the red div it will redirect, as OP asked about the _no-click_ element only.

Comment: Oh. i was trying in your code snippet to click on the red div. It wouldn;t redirect because it's a not secured connection being `http` and not `https`. The error in console is `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Good answer. Voted

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks...updated it a little as well, with some more info.

Comment: @MihaiT And I changed to `https` so it does work now, when clicked on the red div

Comment: :) Now it redirects me to example.com even when i click on the `no-click` blue div. Seems like `stopPropagation` is not working as it should. Strange

Comment: @MihaiT Yes, you are right. Have no clue what goes on here. Will have a look later, so made a change to my answer for now, until I understand why.

Comment: Here is an example https://lajumate.ro/ this is web page with ads, if you hover over the ad the share button and the save button shows up and it`s clickable (the button`s are inside the href)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i make .no-cick div clickable without going to the example.com ? can someone help me? Thx !

Sure. Try this **easiest** and simple way to understand.

One line answer here would be:

**Add onclick="return false".**

To make you understand better, read below:

You just need to add onclick function on the div and return false from it.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div class="test">
     <div class="no-click" onclick="return stopRedirection();">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
stopRedirection = () => {
    alert("Div Clicked!");
  return false;
}
```

I have solved this check the given link below:
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/harshalyeole/9xuavn6x/)

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Simple onclick="return false" is enough. No need for a function.

Comment: Yes, I know that would do too.

I added function to make it understandable.

We can always make code less by refactoring.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote because this is the simplest and fastest solution, but still you might include that in your post. :)

Comment: Here is an example https://lajumate.ro/ this is web page with ads, if you hover over the ad the share button and the save button shows up and it`s clickable (the button`s are inside the href)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div class="test">
     <div class="no-click">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>

css:
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;

}
.no-click {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be this:

```js
document.querySelector('.no-click').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // This line will prevent the browser from following the link
  // Other code you may want to run
});
```

```css
css:
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;

}
.no-click {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div class="test">
     <div class="no-click">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

---

If you just want to have the curser type (pointer) that appears when you hover over a link, you can use CSS:

```css
css:
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;

}
.no-click {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.no-click:hover { /** A rule for the div when the user hovers over it */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div class="test">
     <div class="no-click">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do, just prevent click event of `a` element in case you click on `no-click`, then if not that case just go to the link. Check my codes snippet bellow:

```js
$('.no-click').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('yeah, no need to go!')
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.no-click {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.your-link:hover .no-click {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="your-link" href="https://example.com">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="no-click">

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Here is an example https://lajumate.ro/ this is web page with ads, if you hover over the ad the share button and the save button shows up and it`s clickable (the button`s are inside the href)

Comment: @ElodAndras Yes, my codes had worked for you. I have just edited add more codes for hover states as you mentioned. Run my codes please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, out link action from .no-click div but it should work on anchor ;
    Then use this two blocks;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.no-click').on('click', function(event){    
        event.preventDefault(); 
})
$('a').on('click', function(){
      document.ontouchmove = function(){ return true; }
})
</script>

if you want a also should not work then use only firs blcok!

Thanks!
```